# How to print vector<map<string, int> > in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator

In `vector < map< string, int > >` type.

When I know the index of vector, I just want to print out the string of map, but it does not work.

Error occurs in

```
cout<< myVec.at(intTmp)->first<<"\n";
```

I'm not sure how to access to the map inside of the vector.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <map>
 #include <vector>
using namespace std;

int N, M;
vector<map<string, int> > myVec;

bool isDigits(string& s){

  for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i){
      if(!isdigit(s[i])) return false;
  }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    cin >> N >> M;

    for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i){
        string tmp;
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, tmp);
        myVec.emplace_back(tmp, i);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=M; ++i){
        string tmp1;
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, tmp1);
        if(isDigits(tmp1)){
            int intTmp = atoi(tmp1.c_str());
            cout<< myVec.at(intTmp)->first<<"\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using your map(s) as a single key-value pair. Use `std::pair` for that.

Comment: `myVec[anyIndex]` is not a pointer or an iterator. It's a `map<string, int>` *object*.

Comment: I chose map because I need to use find() functions. pair does not have find() functions. This code only contains print parts, but I need find() to avoid make search functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to use find()"? Do you need to find specific elements in the vector? Or in a map? You can still find elements of the vector with a `vector<pair<string, int>`.

Comment: vector<map<string, int> >::iterator vecIter = myVec.begin()+index;  // is this working?

Comment: There are a data set form of <string, int>. My goal is to access int value when I know the string value only, and to access string value when I know the int value only.

Comment: Still doable... `std::find_if(begin(myVec), end(myVec), [](auto const& p) { return p.first == "TheStringImLookingFor"; });` With that also comes the possibility to have multiple equal "keys" (similar to a `std::multimap`).

Comment: Or perhaps you'd be better of with a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: Okay, I will try to use multimap. Ty. I didn't know that exists. unordered_map? Ok.. I also never used this before, but I will try it.

Comment: If you have access to the boost libraries, you can use [`boost::bimap<std::string, int>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) which allows searching by both sides of a relation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
for(auto map2:myVec)
{   
   for(auto it = map2.begin();it != map2.end();it++)
    cout << (it->first).c_str() << " " << it->second <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a map you have to iterate over the map

```
vector< map<string,int> > myVec;
for( int i=0; i< myVec.size(); i++) {
    for(auto it = myVec[i].begin(); it != myVec[i].end(); it++) {
        cout<<it->first;
    }
}
```